# Spark on AWS EMR: use more executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

**Long story short:** How can I increase the number of executors in Spark on EMR?

**Short story long:**

I am running a pure compute scala spark job (Monte Carlo method to estimate Pi) on EMR 6.3 (Spark 3.1.1). The goal of pure compute is to not have S3/parquet dependencies, and be able to scale without issue, for testing.

```scala
val count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 2147483647).filter { _ =>
    val x = math.random
    val y = math.random
    x*x + y*y < 1
}.count()
println(s"Pi is roughly ${4.0 * count / 2147483647}")
```

There are no settings given to spark-submit, but these global settings given at cluster creation time:

- maximizeResourceAllocation: true (this one is an EMR specificity)
- spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled: true
- spark.default.parallelism: 128
- spark.executor.instances: 0
- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: true

I can confirm via the spark UI that those settings are in effect.

I can confirm as well that `maximizeResourceAllocation` seems to do its job: `spark.executor.core` and `spark.executor.memory` have values matching their instances.

My cluster has 1 master, 4 cores and 4 tasks, all m6g.xlarge (4 vCore, 15.3 GiB memory).

I would thus expect to see 8 executors, maxing out each core and task instance (+ 1 driver, of course, but that's not relevant here).

I only have 2 executors, even if I manually add `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5` for instance.

How can I increase the number of executors for my job?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the optimal configuration for your **FIXED** cluster, better not to use dynamic allocation.

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--num-executors 8 \
--executor-cores 3 \
--executor-memory 13G
```

Comment: Interestingly, with this configuration, I end up with only 1 executor instead of 2. I'm confused.

Comment: can you check the yarn property `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` ? and also, just try with `--executor-memory 8G` just to test quickly if configs are picked up

Comment: `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` of 12288 for `executor-memory` of 8960M (self chosen by EMR). If I explicitly give your settings, I have the same for the NM memory, and 8G as expected for the executor memory.

Comment: do you see just 1 executor with with above config with 8gb ??

Comment: I see 2 as well.

Comment: i am not sure may be `maximizeResourceAllocation: true` is overriding this config. Can you try turning this off ?

Comment: I tried, no effect (or maybe only 1 executor). One interesting thing I did: give 2 GB per executor. That way, I ended having 8, but only across 2 instances. It thus looks like the issue is not spark, but yarn, which allocates 2 instances to spark no matter what. Then Spark does its best within what it can use. I'm digging in that direction now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235137/discussion-between-sanket9394-and-guillaume).

Comment: We are running into a similar issue where I am.  Was a resolution ever reached in the above mentioned chat(it is no longer available to read).